# Create Thumbnail of HtmlImage

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, thumbnails

I am trying to create a thumbnail of HtmlImage.

I was trying to use `GetThumbnailImage` but the system states that htmlimage does not contain a definition for GetThumbnailImage.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
System.Drawing.Image im = (System.Drawing.Image)i.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new System.IntPtr());
```

where i is my HtmlImage. I tried casting it (`(System.Drawing.Image)`). Could anyone point me in the right direction or provide an idea on how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: `HtmlImage` represents a `<img>` HTML tag, you can't cast it to `System.Drawing.Image`. I recommend getting the `Src` property of the `HtmlImage` and create an entirely new `System.Drawing.Image` from that source location.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For now I chose to simply re size images to make them smaller in the structure where I am putting them and larger on hover.